# Windows to Linux migration

Tags: linux, c++

I have been working with windows application development in C++ and SQL for around 3 years.
I want to learn to develop C++ application on Linux and get myself little comfortable with Linux operating system concepts and terminal commands. 
As of now I have installed Ubuntu and codeBlock on my machine, though there's lot of resources available over the internet but It confuses me to decide which one is reliable and useful in day today work. 
I Need some guidance to find the right place to learn Linux.

Comment: There is no right place to learn Linux. It's not a course you can take. Just use Ubuntu (or other distros) to work on your projects and learn some things about it along the way. If you want an answer you need to ask something more specific.

Comment: @TomTom Actually, there is a place like this. It's the user's computer :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn Linux is to force you to use it on a daily basis.

Start by booting your system always in Linux and configure the Window Manager of your choice (GNOME, Mate, KDE, whatever) to suit your needs. Then, setup your favourite webbrowser (chrome, firefox, ...) and install a text editor or an IDE on which you feel comfortable (I myself use Vim but in your case, initially, I would start with Komodo, Atom, Sublime Text or similar). This will probably cover most of your initial needs.

Then for the first weeks, instead of "learning ALL Linux", you only need to learn how to do a particular task when you have the need to do it (i.e.: how do I do this now?).

As you are a programmer, I would recommend you to start with a bash tutorial/manual. Bash is the "default" Linux shell and it's probably the one you're using in your system. Programming in bash is useful not only to create shell scripts to automatize things, but for the daily usage of the system, as for me it's part of the way to work, not just the environment itself.

You should probably start with bash, grep, find, awk, sed, tr, etc and those tools will end being part of your life. I can't understand how people is living without these tools under O.S. like Windows (Mac Os X has them).

Summarizing: you cannot (or shouldn't try to) learn "all Linux". You wouldn't never finish then. Just start with the most useful and important tools: a working X environment, a web browser, your favourite text editor, the bash shell, coreutils like find/grep/sed/etc, development tools like autoconf/automake/make/git (given that you work with C++), etc. In the future you can also use VirtualBox to deploy virtualmachines to develop in (webserver, mysql db server -I wouldn't do it initially-).

Then, while doing this, you'll be "doing things and getting the work done" and you can focus on answering the doubts that can arise while working.

Comment: I'm not an Archer and I'm not a Linux expert at all, but from what I've read Arch Linux is a distro that forces you to learn Linux deeply in order to use it. So perhaps while the learning curve might be steep and it might be time-consuming Arch is the best distro for educational purposes? What do you think about it, Sromero?

Comment: I've never used Arch Linux, I prefer Ubuntu/Mint for the Desktop and CentOS/RedHat for servers. Arch is a very popular distribution but I think it would be an easier and smoother learning curve if you start with a really major distribution that makes you really easy to start in the Linux world, like Ubuntu. You'll also find lots of software repositories and products already compiled for Ubuntu/Mint, making easier and less frustrating your migration. Once you get use to Linux, migrating to other distro without losing things is easy if you keep /home as a separate partition.

Comment: /home contains the user data, as /Users in other O.S. You can easily change from one distribution to another by backing up /home (I would also backup /etc to have access to old system configs in case I want to check something), reinstall Linux, and restore /home (and your etc backup in /home/backup/old_etc). Then if you boot the same Window Manager, you will have pretty much the same Desktop, desktop config, icons, and your applications configured (every app configuration for a user is stored in its home directory). So you can change your distribution later quickly if you want (with few work).

Comment: And from what I've heard operating Arch by unexperienced people may lead to screwing it up.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to find a friend actually using linux. You can learn from inet and many sources, but the initial phase is - you must get information about what to learn. After you see the basic concepts in work (commandline with tab, man pages, configuration in /etc, logs in /var, users in /home, rights, bash programming and utilities, ssh, X display, services), you can go easily by yourself.

I know people, that have started alone, but they sometimes use very strange techniques...

Answer (score 0):

To learn Linux programming there are many sources. A simple Google search lead me to [this](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/) downloadable book which (according to its index) seems to provide a good system programming view and [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg-0.4.pdf).

To learn Linux commands just `ls` /bin and /sbin and `man` those files you will have a wealth of information and you will get to be a guru. According to the guru's deffinition "Guru: Someone who reads the manual (cover to cover)"

To learn shell scripting `man bash` if bash is your thing, otherwise substitute bash for dash, ksh, or whatever shell you want to learn. You can also find interesting [the next](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) manual for bash.